# Angular Material ink-bar using tabs impossible to overwrite styling

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change the styling of the angular material tab component. Especially the ink-bar. But none of the approaches seem to work:

I tried using the

```
.mat-ink-bar{

}
```

as well as some suggestions from stackoverflow:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active
:host ::ng-deep .mat-ink-bar
```

but none of these seem to effect the styling.

I'm using angular 17 and angular material 17.0.3

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to target and override the css variable that this element uses to determine its colour:

```css
.mat-mdc-tab .mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline {
    border-color: var(--mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-color);
}
```

So as a simple example in your `styles.scss` you could do the following:

```css
:root {
--mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-color: red;
}
```

I'd advise against using `root` though and try to scope it more specifically.